# Go channels and I/O

Tags: io, go, channel

First function

> ReadF2C

takes a filename and channel, reads from file and inputs in channel.
Second function

> WriteC2F

takes 2 channels and filename, takes value of each channel and saves the lower value in the output file. I'm sure there is a few syntax errors but i'm new to GO

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!\n\n")
    cs1 := make (chan int)
    var nameinput string = "input.txt"
    readF2C(nameinput,cs1)
    cs2 := make (chan int)
    cs3 := make (chan int)
    cs2 <- 10
    cs2 <- 16
    cs2 <- 7
    cs2 <- 2
    cs2 <- 5
    cs3 <- 8
    cs3 <- 15
    cs3 <- 14
    cs3 <- 1
    cs3 <- 6
    var nameoutput string = "output.txt"
    writeC2F (nameoutput,cs2,cs3)
}

func readF2C (fn string, ch chan int){
    f,err := os.Open(fn)
    r := bufio.NewReader(f)
    for err != nil { // not end of file 

    fmt.Println(r.ReadString('\n'))
    ch <- r.ReadString('\n')
    }

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(r.ReadString('\n'))
            ch <- -1
    }

}
func writeC2F(fn string, // output text file
ch1 chan int, // first input channel
ch2 chan int){
    var j int = 0
    var channel1temp int
    var channel2temp int
        f,_ := os.Create(fn)
        w := bufio.NewWriter(f)
    channel1temp = <-ch1
    channel2temp = <-ch2
    for j := 1; j <= 5; j++ {
     if (channel2temp < channel1temp){

        n4, err := w.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(channel1temp))
        } else{

        n4, err := w.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(channel2temp))
        }
    w.flush()
    }
}
```

This is the error messages I get:

```
prog.go:38: multiple-value r.ReadString() in single-value context
prog.go:65: w.flush undefined (cannot refer to unexported field or method bufio.(*Writer)."".flush)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple errors:

**1)**

Unlike C, Go enforces you to have your curly braces directly after your statements. So for an if case (and the same for func), instead of doing it like this:

```
if (channel2temp < channel1temp)
{
```

use this

```
if channel2temp < channel1temp {
```

**2)**

There is no `while` in Go. Use `for`

```
for {
...
}
```

or

```
for channel1temp != null || channel2temp != null {
...
}
```

**3)**

Usage of non-declared variables. Often easy to fix by making a short variable declaration the first time you initialize the variable. So instead of:

```
r = bufio.NewReader(file)
```

use

```
r := bufio.NewReader(file)
```

**4)**

Trying to a assign multi-value return into a single variable. If a function returns two values and you only need one, the variable you don't want can be discarded by assigning it to `_`. So instead of:

```
file := os.Open(fn)
```

use

```
file, _ := os.Open(fn)
```

**but best practice would be to catch that error:**

```
file, err := os.Open(fn)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

There are more errors on top of this, but maybe it will get you started.
I also suggest reading [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) since it will explain many of the things I've just mentioned.

**Edit:**

And there are help online for sure. It might be a new language, but the online material is really useful. Below is a few that I used when learning Go:

- [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html): Good document on how to write idiomatic Go code
- [The Go programming language Tour](http://tour.golang.org/): Online tour of Go with interactive examples.
- [Go By Example](https://gobyexample.com/): Interactive examples of Go programs, starting with Hello World.
- [Go Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec): Surprisingly readable for being a specification. Maybe not a start point, but very useful.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, syntax is was a major problem but I am more concerned about those of file reading and writing as well as end of file conditions to fullfill the requirement of the program, I edited my code to what I have right now

Comment: Before debugging the logic, we should get that syntax straight. Your Line 38 problem is the 4) issue: Since `r.Readstring()` returns two values, you can't directly put the value in the channel. You first do a read `s, err := r.ReadString('\n')`, then an error check, and then putting the value (`s`  in my case) into the channel. Line 65 is a simple case sensitive error: use `w.Flush()` instead of `w.flush()`.

Comment: You're going to have to handle syntax errors once you're really coding, so now's as good a time as any to start.